# Why is the feathersjs app.setup method breaking websocket connection

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

In the App.js file these are the last few lines:

```
app.configure(initialise)
app.configure(enableCronJobs)

module.exports = app
```

initialise comes from here (in the app.js file)

```
const initialise = require('./initialise')
```

the initialize file looks like the following

```
module.exports = async (app: App) => {
    try {
        app.setup()

        await app.get('sequelizeSync')
        const { total: RolesCount } = await app.service('roles').find()

        if (RolesCount === 0) {
            await Promise.all(
                roles.map(role =>
                    app
                        .service('roles')
                        .create(role, { useSequelizeModel: true }),
                ),
            )
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('initialise', app, e) // eslint-disable-line
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the console (and it repeats):

```
error: Page not found {"type":"FeathersError","name":"NotFound","code":404,"className":"not-found","data":{"url":"/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"},"errors":{}}
```

The actual create queries function work and data is inserted into the database.

The websocket connection though is broken and any client cannot connect to the service as long as I have the app.setup() method inside the initialize function.

I need the app.setup() function to be called so that the database is ready, else I have an error as the following:

```
relation {TABLE} does not exist
```

Any suggestions, tips, etc... are welcome.

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 2):

`setup` is meant to be called with a `server` parameter which is missing from your code. When you call `app.listen`, `app.setup` is called so you don't want to call `setup` here.

Instead, you can replace `app.setup` with your own version, making sure to call the old `setup` function.

```js
module.exports = async (app: App) => {
    const oldSetup = app.setup;

    app.setup = function (...args) {
      const result = oldSetup.apply(this, ...args);
      try {
          await app.get('sequelizeSync')
          const { total: RolesCount } = await app.service('roles').find()

          if (RolesCount === 0) {
              await Promise.all(
                  roles.map(role =>
                      app
                          .service('roles')
                          .create(role, { useSequelizeModel: true }),
                  ),
              )
          }
      } catch (e) {
          console.log('initialise', app, e) // eslint-disable-line
      }
      return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if I do the above, I still get the following error:
error: Page not found 
{"type":"FeathersError","name":"NotFound","code":404,"className":"not-found","data":{"url":"/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"},"errors":{}}

Comment: Do you have socket.io configured?
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#appconfiguresocketio

Comment: Ye, the socket api works, it only breaks when I add the app.setup as above.